# Keras CNN layers as a function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, convolution

How can you represent a 1D-Convolutional Layer as an operation?
For instance, fully connected layers like this:

```
model = Sequential([

    Dense(32, batch_input_shape=(None,100), init='he_normal', activation='relu),

    Dense(1, init='he_normal', activation='linear)
])
```

Can be written as a function like this:

```
def pred(inputs,model_weights):

    weights=np.vstack([model_weights[0],model_weights()[1]]) 

    inputs=np.hstack([inputs,np.zeros(inputs.shape[0]).reshape(inputs.shape[0],1)])

    inputs[:,-1]=1

    prediction=np.dot(inputs,weights) 

    prediction[prediction<0]=0              ### RELU after 1st layer

    weights=np.vstack([model_weights[2],model_weights[3]])

    prediction=np.hstack([prediction,np.zeros(prediction.shape[0]).reshape(prediction.shape[0],1)])

    prediction[:,-1]=1

    prediction=np.dot(prediction,weights)

    return prediction


weights_from_model = model.get_weights()

x=test_data

pred(x,weights_from_model)
```

First of all, am I understanding the Dense layers correctly?

Secondly, how do you represent a CNN layer like those in the code below?

```
model = Sequential([

    InputLayer(batch_input_shape=(None,100,1)),

    Convolution1D(nb_filter=16, filter_length=8, activation='relu', border_mode='same', init='he_normal', input_shape=(None,100,1)),

    Convolution1D(nb_filter=32, filter_length=8, activation='relu', border_mode='same', init='he_normal'), 

    MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4),

    Flatten(),

    Dense(output_dim=32, activation='relu', init='he_normal'),

    Dense(output_dim=1, input_dim=32, activation='linear'),
])
```

Creating this function is necessary for my project in order to define a Theano function (although I have used Tensorflow to train the weights) that returns the Jacobian matrix of the output wrt the input data. The weights are already trained and set, it is just a matter of putting the layers in the form of a python function.

***EDIT

How do you add the bias weights to the CNN layer?

For instance, my first layer has dimensions:
(8, 1, 1, 16)

With a bias with dimensions:
(16,)

Which is easy enough to concatenate together to get dimensions:
(9, 1, 1, 16)

but for the next layer I have dimensions:
(8, 1, 16, 32)

with a bias with dimensions:
(32,)

How can I combine this into one weight matrix?

Comment: You can look at the `Convolution1D` source code? I assume you know that Theano has a function for convolution: [`T.nnet.conv2d`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html#theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d). Can't you just use that?

Comment: That would be perfect. I don't see an equivalent for 1D though. Can I still use T.nnet.conv2d with 1D inputs?

Comment: Yes, you can. On how to do it, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147403/1586200) or even better - [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/theano_backend.py/#conv1d). You can always write a code in numpy for 1D convolution and match its output with Theano convolution to make sure your Theano implementation is correct. I did something similar for 2D convolution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42742549/1586200).

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect